# How do I grant access to a developer to access my Azure b2c directory?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have recently created an azure b2c tenant for my app to manage users.

I see the directory in my list of directories along with my default AD directory.

I'm able to select that directory which then gives me full access to set up user flows, manage users etc etc

I have a developer on my team, who is currently in my main ad.  I would like him to carry out some work on the azure b2c directory.

I've tried many different combinations, including giving him owner on the main subscription and global admin on the various resource groups that contain the azure b2c tenant but nothing I try allows him to access the b2c directory.

I was hoping it would be visible in his list of directories.

When I go to the users within azure b2c I see his name, and he has Global Admin for assigned role.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [invite him as a guest account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tenant-management-manage-administrator#invite-an-administrator-guest-account) in the B2C tenant itself, he'll then be able to switch to the B2C directory in the Azure Portal.

If you've already invited him to the tenant using the steps outlined in that link and he still can't access the B2C directory in the Azure Portal then try the following:

1. Have him sign out & back in (or sign-in in another browser/incognito tab) to make sure the updated permissions are being applied
2. Remove him from the B2C directory and re-add him using the steps linked above.

If he still doesn't have access after that then I think you'll need to get in touch with Microsoft support as it's a more specific problem to your directory or his account.